# ImageView scaling inside layout when it should not

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I've got a simple vertical layout with an editText and an ImageView under it.
The problem is that when the user edits the EditText and it gets too long, then the ImageView under it ends up being "crushed" and resized in order to avoid screen scrolling, like this:

[image: problem]

When I'd want the opposite, the image size being kept and the screen scrolling being allowed when it overflows.

By searching online, I thought I had to change the `scaleType` and `adjustViewBounds` parameters, but I had no luck playing with them.
Even manualy setting a high `minHeight` doesn't seem to fix the problem, strangely.
Any advice?

EDIT: xml added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Nothing here. Type your thoughts?"
            android:background="?attr/background_card"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="16dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"                 android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:paddingRight="14dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your layout xml file?

Comment: sure, juste edited the op

Answer (score 0):

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

> LinearLayout also supports assigning a weight to individual children
>   with the android:layout_weight attribute. This attribute assigns an
>   "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space is should
>   occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to
>   fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a
>   weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is
>   assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight.
>   Default weight is zero.
>
> For example, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a
>   weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field
>   without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by
>   its content. The other two will expand equally to fill the space
>   remaining after all three fields are measured. If the third field is
>   then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it is now declared more
>   important than both the others, so it gets half the total remaining
>   space, while the first two share the rest equally.

Theoretically I think it should solve your problem.